# extracting only the domainname, port number of first path

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, url

```
str1="https://111.111.111.111:2222/cpsess8993738132/scripts4/listaccts/"
str2="https://111.111.111.111:2222/cpsess8993738132/"
str3="https://111.111.111.111:2222/cpsess8993738132/cgi/server/xyz.cgi|Server     Security & Firewall|111.22.33.31.|0|1|0||0|2221331130315786|fzerstxBjUiZ"
```

How can I extract only upto the `https://IP:port/firstpath/`rest/of/the/paths/and_some_thing_else

I want to extract up to only https://IP:port/firstpath/

How can I do it in shell script?

Comment: i have tried many, awk, sed, string ops and trying many now.

Comment: @Mani Do you consider that a useful response? Why do you think he asked that?

Comment: echo $string | sed 's/\//\n/4'
 ==> This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
> str1="https://111.111.111.111:2222/cpsess8993738132/scripts4/listaccts/"
> rest="${str1#*//?*/}"
> str="${str1%"$rest"}"
> echo "$str"
https://111.111.111.111:2222/
```

Comment: The IP Address and Other ports will keep changing.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying since yesterday evening, Within few minutes after posting in StackExchange I found a solution.

string="https://111.22.33.44:5557/xyzsess81122334442/scripts4/listaccts/xfercpanel/some"
    Thanks for your help...

```
echo $string | sed 's/\//\/\n/4'


>     echo $string | sed 's/\//\/\n/4'
>        s/ -> replace command
>       \/ => find all /
>       replace with \/\n -> \and newline 
>      /4 --> 4th occurance
```